# To pull out data using superset sqllab from same column twice using different conditions

Tags: sql

My table schema consists of Source of lead, Qualified (yes/no) and some other fields.

What I want is to pull out table such that it shows something like this from SQLLAB

Table Schema
Source, Qualified ('Yes'/'No'/'blanks' or ' ')

Source Count(Total Qualified) Count(Qualified only 'Yes')
A            10                    8
B            20                    11
C            5                     1

The above result groups all sources and then shows the above result in a pivot kind of form.

I am unable to figure out how to write query for this type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

So it can be fine?

```
with source_lead as (
                      select 'A' as source, 'Yes'    as qualified from dual union all
                      select 'A' as source, 'No'     as qualified from dual union all
                      select 'A' as source, 'blanks' as qualified from dual union all
                      select 'A' as source, ' '      as qualified from dual union all
                      select 'B' as source, 'Yes'    as qualified from dual union all
                      select 'B' as source, 'Yes'    as qualified from dual union all                      
                      select 'B' as source, 'No'     as qualified from dual union all
                      select 'C' as source, ' '      as qualified from dual
                    )
             select a.source, 
                    count(*) as Tot_Qualified,
                    (
                     select count(*) 
                       from source_lead b
                      where b.source = a.source 
                        and b.qualified = 'Yes' 
                    ) as Tot_Yes
               from source_lead a
              group by a.source 
              order by a.source;

SOURCE TOT_QUALIFIED TOT_YES
------ ------------- ----------
A      4             1
B      3             2
C      1             0
```

Thank you